# Cannot enable "Microsoft.Container Service" in Azure

Tags: azure, preview, azure-aks

I tried to run `az provider register --namespace Microsoft.ContainerService` with more than 2 hours. However, it still shows *WindowsPreview* in **NotRegistered** status.

It mentioned only *It takes a few minutes for the registration to complete* in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/windows-container-cli) but it has been taking more than 2 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right command should be this:

```
az feature register --name WindowsPreview --namespace Microsoft.ContainerService
```

And the command you run is to refresh the registration of the `Microsoft.ContainerService resource provider`.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the answer is provided by Charles, i would like to attach the list of commands that would help others,

```
az feature register --name "WindowsPreview" --namespace "Microsoft.ContainerService"
```

and list of [`commands`](https://github.com/denniszielke/container_demos/blob/2cb265fca1feb33108d70ba1429ef448ea03b3c4/Features.md)